# Xamarin XAML, how to bind List of Tuples to Bindable Layout

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a List<(string a, string b)> itemsources, and I want to to Bind it to a bindable layout, what would be the syntax for that?

```
  <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding itemsources}">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout Spacing="4">
                  <Label Text="{Binding a???}" />
                  <Label Text= "{Binding b????}"/>
                </StackLayout>
              </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
          </StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you look at the docs for [Tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-2?view=netcore-3.1), you'll see that the properties are named

- Item1
- Item2

so your XAML would be

```
<Label Text="{Binding Item1}" />
<Label Text="{Binding Item2}" />
```

Answer (score 4):

You should not use **ValueTuple** because it's a struct, it won't work in binding. You should use a regular **Tuple** which is a reference type.

Change :

```
List<(string a, string b)>
```

to :

```
List<Tuple<string, string>>
```

Your binding should look like this :

```
  <StackLayout Spacing="4">
      <Label Text="{Binding Item1}" />
      <Label Text="{Binding Item2}" />
  </StackLayout>
```